# Идея ругается на нехватку памяти Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, mysql

Идея ругается на нехватку памяти, провожу парсинг файла 1500М с последующим INSERT в мускул, и потом select.-Xmx1024m -Xms256m и SET GLOBAL max-... в мускул тоже установил, но увы Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Вас не смущает, что 1500 это больше чем 1024?

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'; возвращает 'max_allowed_packet', '33554432'

Comment: точнее 1572M xml

Comment: То есть вас по-прежнему не смущает, что 1572 больше чем 1024?

Comment: У меня задание пропарсить этот файл, залить в мускул и выбрать повторяющиеся

Comment: Очень жаль, что вас это не смущает.

Comment: А точнее можно?

Comment: Вы выделили джаве памяти меньше чем размер файла. Естественно её не хватит, её ж ведь меньше чем надо.

Comment: Попробуйте читать файл частями или увеличить размер доступной вашей программе памяти.

Comment: поставил ровно1572 все равно

Comment: Теперь вспоминаем про всякие внутренние структуры и технические объекты, которые появятся после парсинга и тоже занимают память в дополнение к собственно содержимому файла. Нужно ставить хотя бы 4096, а может даже и 8192

Comment: Ну а вообще, не видя код парсера, говорить о чём-то конкретном и о реальных причинах нехватки памяти не получится

Comment: private static void parseFile(String fileName) throws Exception
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new File(fileName));

        findEqualVoters(doc);
        fixWorkTimes(doc);
    }

Comment: static void findEqualVoters(Document doc) 
    {
        NodeList voters = doc.getElementsByTagName("voter");
        int votersCount = voters.getLength();
        for(int i = 0; i < votersCount; i++)
        {
            Node node = voters.item(i);
            NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
            String name = attributes.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
            String birthDay = attributes.getNamedItem("birthDay").getNodeValue();

            DBConnection.countVoter(name, birthDay);
        }
        DBConnection.executeMultiInsert();
    }

Comment: 8196 не хватило

Comment: Значит нужно или ещё увеличивать (и бежать в магазин покупать планку памяти), или всё-таки искать способ читать файл не целиком, а по частям, как советовали выше

Comment: хорошо, буду пилить

Comment: Обычно в подобных ситуациях рекомендуют SAX-парсер

Answer (score 0):

Да, sax парсер помог, отсутствие multyinsert, плюс 8192 и set global max в мускуле